# How to run React useEffect only once and property update state with setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The following functional React component runs the useEffect hook twice, even though an empty array [] is passed as a second argument and the component is added to the page only once:

```js
const Tips = () => {
  const [idx, setIdx] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIdx(idx + 1)
    }, 1000)
  }, []) // empty array: run effect only once
  return <>{idx}</>
}
```

How to make sure the interval is started only once inside the useEffect function callback?

Also, the state idx is updated only once, the component outputs 0 and later on 1. How to change the component so that the idx counter keeps increasing?

Comment: Can you please show where you are using your `Tips` component? From this code alone your `useEffect` should only fire once - is there anything that could be causing it to re-mount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do what you need:

```
const Tips = () => {
  const [idx, setIdx] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("start use effect");
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIdx(idx=>idx + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return ()=>clearInterval(interval)
  }, []); // empty array: run effect only once
  return <>{idx}</>;
};
```

the trick is here `setIdx(idx=>idx + 1)`. Instead of `setIdx(idx + 1)`. Because useEffect runs once, interval handler creates a closure over your initial idx value which is 0 and on every setIdx it just sets it to 0+1 and then component re-rendered with 1.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is only called once when I try to implement it. The interval function is however stuck in a loop. I think it is unclear what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: The goal is to increment the idx state varia on each interval tick, so the component should render 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on

Comment: Okey, then when I try your code I get the expected outcome. I get one "start" on mount and then nothing else.